# Изменение круговой диаграммы в OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Свойство Value у PieSlice доступно только для чтения. 
Получается, что для обновления диаграммы нужно каждый раз удалять сегмент из PieSeries.Slices и добавлять заново?
Такой вариант мне не нравится сложностью и тем, что при повторном добавлении меняются цвета и порядок сегментов.
Сейчас просто удаляю все сегменты и добавляю заново. Но это плохо тем. что если один из первых сегментов был удален в процессе работы, то все цвета меняются.
А отдельно поддерживать еще и список цветов не хочется.

Comment: `PieSeries.Slices` является `IList<PieSlice>`, нельзя просто с помощью индексатора заменить нужный сегмент? `PieSeries.Slices[10] = new PieSlice(PieSeries.Slices[10].Label, newValue);`